# Play Framework [1.2.4]: unique constraints for an entity

Tags: jpa, playframework, unique, unique-constraint

I am using playframwork with mySQL for my web application. I have a table which requires an unique_constraint on multiple columns.

I have the entity defined as follows...

```
package models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table",
                  uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames =
                                                          { "col_1", "col_2" }) })
public class Table extends Model{

  @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "col_1")
       public Column1 col1;

       @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "col_2")
       public Column2 col2;

       @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "col_3")
       public Column3 col_3;

}
```

Column1 and Column2 are different entities with relationship with
Table entity.

When i try to insert data with duplicate "col_1 and col_2" values as
shown below i am getting no error. The data is inserted fine in the
table (MySQL).

```
Table table1 = new Table();
table1.col1 = new Column1("1");
table1.col2= new Column2("2);
table1.col3= new Column3("3");
table1.save();

Table table2 = new Table();
table2 .col1 = new Column1("1");
table2 .col2= new Column2("2);
table2 .col3= new Column3("3");
table2 .save();
```

Do i need to create unique_constraint manually on the table?

Please help me understand, if i have anything missing in the above
implementation

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 2):

If the table is not created by JPA, yes, you'll have to manually create the unique constraints for them to be taking affect.

If the table does not pre-exist, JPA should create the constraint for you.

JPA does not create a constraint on an already existing table.